# Can LibreOffice Base directly use MySQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, libreoffice, odbc, libreoffice-base, openoffice-base

From what I can see, LibreOffice Base comes with an HSQLDB implementation by default. I understand that ODBC allows users to connect to different data sources, including databases that use different flavors of SQL.

What I'm significantly hazier on is this: Is there a way for me to use MySQL syntax within LibreOffice or OpenOffice? If so, would someone be able to describe it or link me to some docs? (I may just be using the wrong google queries.)

Whether you have an answer or not, thanks for your time in reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you download the correct 32 or 64 bit version depending on your version of libreoffice.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.2.html#downloads
install the odbc connector

control panel
admin tools
ODBC

User DSN
Add
Mysql ODBC......

New dialog
dsn: whatever
tcp/ip:

fill in the rest of the credentials
Click test and make sure everything is OK.

when I launch libre  office base 4.0.3 
I get a database wizard
What do you want to do?

Connect to an exiting database:
select ODBC 
Browse
select the ODBC you created above.
connect using ODBC

username (again)
check password if required

Finish 
Save name it whatever you want.

login again
and your done

Comment: This definitely sets up the connection. I haven't tested the actual syntax yet, but since nobody else is answering, I'm definitely going to mark this as the accepted answer, since I really appreciate the time you took to submit detailed steps.

In case you feel like going above and beyond: Do you know of any MySQL-specific query language I could use to test the syntax side of this -- something that wouldn't work in other versions of SQL?

Comment: @user49982  Either you will be able to access it or not.
select * from <tablename>
should result in data.  Unfortunately the statement is generic SQL, but it is still effective.  The table exists on the server not inside of LibreOffice.  If LibreOffice Base can see the data your in.

Answer (score 0):

The Query window (which can only be used for SELECT statements) by default has a Base parser which is optimized for the most common functions in an old version of HSQLDB (version 1.8 is what is bundled with OpenOffice, while the current version is 2.3).  If you need to use a syntax in the query window that the parser objects to, you can turn off the parser by selecting Edit->Run SQL Command Directly.

If you want to run any kind of SQL that is not a SELECT statement, use the Tools->SQL window.  This window always sends SQL directly to the database (no parser).

If you want to write an SQL statement inside a form or form control that the parser objects to, these objects have a property "Analyze SQL Command" that can be set to "No" to disable the parser.

Having the parser disabled on a query, form, or form control disables some form features that require the parser (notably field linking).  Sometimes it is better to save the relevant SQL as a View.